# Static background for a web page

Tags: html, css

I've seen a few time websites where the background stay static while the page scrolls. How is it done and is it possible with the background that is tiling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`background-position:fixed;` I believe. Yes it's possible with tiling

Comment: Ahh, I keep always forgetting about "fixed"... You're probably right. Does that mean that using this for tiling background is more beneficial in terms of some memory savings since it only tiles the area of the visible screen? Or it makes no difference since it's the same image being used? Just curious.